# KSQL - Convert XML to JSON/AVRO

Tags: json, xml, apache-kafka, avro, ksqldb

I am interested in loading data from SQL Server to Kafka . One of the column in a table is XML one. How can we transform XML to JSON or AVRO formant in KSQL streams?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) and  [XML Single Message Transform (SMT)](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml).

For example:

```
transforms=Key
transforms.Key.type=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.transform.xml.FromXml$Value
# The following values must be configured.
transforms.Key.schema.path = < Configure me >
```

For more information you can refer to [this Github repository](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml).

Comment: Thanks @Giorgos . I am looking something in KSQL streams.

Comment: @RaghavaReddy You have to get data into Kafka before you can use KSQL. Kafka Connect would be used to do that