# is it possible to convert XML data into JSON Format in Kafka

Tags: json, xml, apache-kafka

i have requirement publisher send XML data in to apache Kafka cluster and my consumer need data into JSON format.

Is it possible Apache Kafka can convert XML data into JSON?

Answer (score 0):

> Apache Kafka can convert [...]

No. Kafka itself stores binary data without conversion.

*Your client code* is responsible for deserialization, parsing, reformatting, and re-serializing into other formats

If you have consumers and producers that do not agree on a uniform format, it would be the responsibility of one of the parties (probably the consumer or the Kafka administrators) to come up with a standard way to provide a conversion service.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60061371/ksql-convert-xml-to-json-avro/), but KSQL doesn't support XML last I checked, so you'd have to at least use Kafka Streams, although you could borrow some logic from [this project](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-xml), however it stops short of actually providing JSON output

You might be able to use that project with MirrorMaker2 since it's built on Kafka Connect as part of the same cluster, but YMMV since that's not a recommended pattern

Comment: Thanks for updated Cricketeer, yes if they send XML data then Kafka cluster side store the data into binary format. so by using Mongo DB sink connector i can transfer the data into JSON format  correct??

Comment: You should be able to use the mentioned transform as part of the Mongo sink, yes

Comment: i have one more query, i want install connector in HDinsignt where i can add (Like separate instance i need to add for Kafka connector) if yes please let me know any doc or steps available to add kafka connector in HDInsight

Comment: To run Connect, find a node with Kafka installed. Look in the `bin` directory of Kafka for `connect-distributed.sh`. Adding connectors themselves is no different than any other environment